# Python: How do I fill textbox faster using Splinter?

Tags: python, textbox, splinter

I want to get text from Google Sheets and paste it inside a textbox in Buffer using web automation through Splinter.

Here's how I did it:

```
browser.find_by_css('#textbox').fill(long_utf8_text)
# or
browser.find_by_css('#textbox').type(long_utf8_text)
# basically I get the same results with both
```

Though when I do that, it starts typing really slowly and the text I have is really long and encoded in UTF-8.

My whole project uses Splinter, so I can't change it in case you have a suggestion for that.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue and make Splinter fill the text instantly and in UTF-8 at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[`.type()`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/e8c027280d40cb0452c545c58bf1aca96cbd2ee8/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L743) sends the value char by char, but [`.fill()`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/e8c027280d40cb0452c545c58bf1aca96cbd2ee8/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L556) should populate the entire value in one go. How big is your value?

You could try a workaround like the following to make sure you bypass any logic in Splinter or Selenium regarding form input population:

```
browser.execute_script(
    'document.getElementById("textbox").value = {}'.format(json.dumps(long_utf8_text)
)
```